# Как отфильтровать результат запроса из Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Используя Mongoose с помощью find({}) получаю все документы, но при переборе в цикле там много всего вспомогательного (смотрел, выводя в консоль), но мне нужны ТОЛЬКО поля.
Есть ли способ фильтрации?
При:

```
User.find({}, function(err, docs){
  for(let key in docs) {
    console.log(docs[key]);
  }
});
```

Вот часть вывода `docs[key]`:

```
{ status: 'active',
ID: '2',
_id: 5877e9f30d64858af7b3dd6c }
{ [Function] numAsyncPres: 1 }
[Function: wrappedPointCut]
{ '$__original_save': 
[ { [Function: fn] isAsync: false },
{ [Function: fn] isAsync: true } ],
'$__original_validate': [ { [Function: fn] isAsync: true } ],
'$__original_remove': [ { [Function: fn] isAsync: true } ] }
{ '$__original_save': [],
'$__original_validate': [],
'$__original_remove': [] }
{ [Function] numAsyncPres: 1 }
[Function: wrappedPointCut]
{ [Function] numAsyncPres: 1 }
[Function: wrappedPointCut]
NativeConnection {
base: 
Mongoose {
connections: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Circular] ],
plugins: [],
models: {},
modelSchemas: { User: [Object], Patient: [Object] },
options: { pluralization: true } },
collections: 
{ users: 
NativeCollection {
collection: [Object],
opts: [Object],
name: 'users',
collectionName: 'users',
conn: [Circular],
queue: [],
buffer: false,
emitter: [Object] } },
models: 
{ User: 
{ [Function: model]
hooks: [Object],
base: [Object],
modelName: 'User',
model: [Function: model],
db: [Circular],
discriminators: undefined,
schema: [Object],
collection: [Object],
Query: [Object],
'$__insertMany': [Function],
insertMany: [Function] } },
config: { autoIndex: true },
```

Мне нужно только это:

```
{ status: 'active',
    ID: '2',
    _id: 5877e9f30d64858af7b3dd6c }
```

Есть идеи как это отфильтровать самому, но не хочется писать костыль.

Comment: Luke, use the `select`?

Comment: Не то. Я мел ввиду, что помимо того что я запрашиваю, при переборе через цикл перебирается всякая мишура типа __parentArray. То что я не задавал, а рабочие методы из коробки.

Comment: Приведите пример кода и что у Вас случилось. Гаданием никто тут не занимается. Хотя кто знает...

Answer (score 0):

Нашел выход:

```
find({}).lean().exec(function(err, docs){});
```